# Expression.OrElse, dynamically creating a condition

Tags: linq, dynamic

I am attempting to create a dynamic where clause using the standard expression API.

```
var query = (
            from p in Parties
                orderby p.PartyId
                orderby p.FullName
                select p
).AsQueryable();


 Expression<Func<Party, bool>> @fn = (p) => SqlMethods.Like(p.FullName, "%smith%") || SqlMethods.Like(p.Person.FirstName, "%smith%");
 Expression<Func<Party, bool>> @sn = (p) => SqlMethods.Like(p.Person.FirstName, words[0]);

 ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Party), "p");
 Expression orelse = Expression.OrElse(
  Expression.Lambda(@fn, pe),
  Expression.Lambda(@sn, pe)
 );
```

The expressions above will ultimately be added to a where clause.
I need to add a bunch of 'likes'.

How do I do this?

I get InvalidOperationException on the operator OrElse
I have also tried `Expression.Or`

Thanks

Regards

Craig.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out PredicateBuilder?

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

It can make dynamically creating expressions for where clauses much easier.